# What is this SAS note saying? ODS PDF(WEB) printed no output

Tags: sas

What is this SAS note saying?  ODS PDF(WEB) printed no output.

I have not requested the saving of a pdf file. This code is just at the beginning of my program code.

```
 98         /* ODS STATEMENTS */
 99         ODS LISTING GPATH='&sasworklocation';
 100        ODS LISTING GPATH='c:\data';
 101        ods path reset;
 102        ods _ALL_ close;
 NOTE: ODS PDF(WEB) printed no output. 
       (This sometimes results from failing to place a RUN statement before 
        the ODS PDF(WEB) CLOSE statement.)
        ods trace off;
```

Thank you.
MM

Comment: Where are the other 97 lines of code?  Are you using SAS/Studio or Enterprise Guide perhaps?  Those usually have code they submit for you.

Comment: The macro ridits uses about 8 macros which I have listed at top of the macro itself. None of these macros refer to pdf at all. It looks like code is automatically generating here by SAS university.  I have seen this message multiple times now as I learn to use SAS university with no apparent explanation. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SAS EG or Studio it submits some code at the beginning of each submission and teh end. You can turn the display of this code on/off but you cannot stop it. You likely have PDF selected as an output options somewhere or the automatic code is generating that message. You can probably ignore it safely.

Comment: Are you using SAS Studio or EG? Either way go to options and look for an option related to 'wrapper code' and you can usually control some of the display.

Comment: Are you using EG or Studio?

Comment: If EG, go to Options>Results>Results General -> deselect `Show generated wrapper code in SAS log`

Comment: I should have answered this before. I am using SAS Studio in SAS University. I found I am able to reduce log output when I unchecked LOG Options-Show generated code in SAS log preferences. I thought that would stop all log output activity. Cheers, and thank you. I must say though I miss Enterprise Guide.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce log output in SAS University uncheck LOG Options-Show generated code in SAS log preferences.